# How to get Page Library Id and Page Id in ribbon custom action for Publishing Pages?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, ribbon, publishing-page, custom-actions

I have the following custom action declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction Id="17f8cf1d-c8bf-4721-986b-d4106d77343c.RibbonCustomAction2"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
            Sequence="10001"
            HostWebDialog="true" 
            HostWebDialogHeight="300" 
            HostWebDialogWidth="300"
            Title="Dialog Title">   
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert.Content.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.PageActions.RibbonCustomAction2Button"
              Alt="Invoke RibbonCustomAction2" 
              Sequence="100" 
              Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction2ButtonRequest"
              LabelText="CustomAction2"
              TemplateAlias="o1"
              Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
              Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction2ButtonRequest"
                      CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/Image.aspx?listId={ListId}&amp;selectedListId={SelectedListId}&amp;itemId={ItemId}&amp;selectedItemId={SelectedItemId}"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension >
</CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Custom action works and is displayed in Insert tab for Publising Pages, but I can't get the current Page Library and Page Ids. Parameters passed to Image.aspx:

```
?listId={ListId}&selectedListId=null&itemId={ItemId}&selectedItemId=null&IsDlg=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these parameters are picked up from the QueryString. They are related to current selected item. `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643(v=office.12).aspx`.

Your best bet would be to write some javascript in the handler as described over here `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458385.aspx`

Within the javascript function, you can get the query string and parse it to get what you need.

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220046.aspx "CustomAction cannot contain JavaScript" in Apps for Sharepoint. When I try to write simple "javascript:alert('Hello');" I get "Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': There were errors when validating the App Package."